# table with an url image inside header

Tags: html, image, url, header, datatable

I have a sortable table in html and looking to put an add.png inside each table header so if a user wants to add another url - they just click the add.png and redirects them to the addurl.php (if they click outside it will still sort the table just like normal). Right now it sorting when I click on the .png and/or outside it. If this something that can't be done, I've also thought about trying to add a final row with [add another site] but have no idea how to work it into the $j++ so it appears at the final row.

[what it looks like](http://i179.photobucket.com/albums/w312/Vermino/Statisticsproblem.png)

[PHP snippet]

```
        <table class="datatable sortable selectable full">  
        <thead>
        <tr class="theader">
            <th width="100%">           
            <b><li><img src="images/logos/googlebuzz-2-icon.png" height="18" border="0" />Google <a href="addurl.php"><img src="img/icons/add.png" height="18" border="0" align="right"/></a></li></b>  
            </th>           
            <th>                        
            <b>Coins</b>            
            </th>
            <th>            
            <b>CPC</b>          
            </th>                   
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>             
<?
  $site2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE `user`='{$data->login}' ORDER BY `cpc` DESC");
  for($j=1; $site = mysql_fetch_object($site2); $j++)
{
?>      
            <tr>
                <td>                            
                <? if($site->banned == 1){ ?><font color="red"><? }else{ ?><font color="green"><? } echo($site->title); ?></font><a href="editurl.php?id=<? echo $site->id;?>" class="action-button-small" title="Edit URL"><span class="edit"></span></a>                  
                </td>                           
                <td align="right">                      
                <? if($site->points <= 10){ ?><font color="red"><? }else{ ?><font color="green"><? } echo($site->points); ?></font><a href="addcoins.php?id=<? echo $site->id;?>" class="action-button-small" title="Add Coins"><span class="add"></span></a>
                </td>
                <td>                
                <? echo $site->cpc;?>           
                </td>                   
            </tr>
            <?}?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, instead of a `for` loop, you should use `while`:

```
while($site = mysql_fetch_object($site2))
```

If you want to add a final row, just add it outside the iteration, before `</tbody>`:

```
<tbody>
<? while($site = mysql_fetch_object($site2)): ?>
  <tr>
    <td>                            
      <? if($site->banned == 1){ ?><font color="red"><? }else{ ?><font color="green"><? } echo($site->title); ?></font><a href="editurl.php?id=<? echo $site->id;?>" class="action-button-small" title="Edit URL"><span class="edit"></span></a>                  
    </td>                           
    <td align="right">                      
      <? if($site->points <= 10){ ?><font color="red"><? }else{ ?><font color="green"><? } echo($site->points); ?></font><a href="addcoins.php?id=<? echo $site->id;?>" class="action-button-small" title="Add Coins"><span class="add"></span></a>
    </td>
    <td>                
      <? echo $site->cpc;?>           
    </td>                   
  </tr>
<? endwhile; ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <a href="addurl.php">[add another site]</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

It seems you are using a javascript to do the sorting. I don't know if that can be changed so your add button in the header works.

Comment: Thank you so much Mischa.. (yea, javascript is doing the sorting) but it works perfectly now. I seriously google'd for an hour on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it's the final row by checking the actual row against all rows:

```
$site2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE `user`='{$data->login}' ORDER BY `cpc` DESC");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($site2);
$i = 0;
```

And add this in your for loop:

```
$i++;
if($rows == $i) {
    // do something only at the final row
}
```